# client receive messages from the server asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a client(`ClientA`) that connects to the server. When another client(`ClientB`) is connected, server sends a message to the first client to inform him that another client has been connected. 
When the `ClientB` makes any changes `ClientA` gets informed by the server.

My problem is that I do not know how to do this. Any idea how to have the client wait and receive for a message from the server anytime using Java sockets?

Comment: There are so many ways to implement this: sockets, JMS, webservice (SOAP or REST), websocket, and many other ways of integration. You first need to choose what technology is suitable for your purpose. Then you need to implement the Observer pattern over selected technology abstraction.

Comment: I said Java sockets :)